# MacBook Pro used in smoking area

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

My late 2012 Retina MacBook Pro has been used in area's in which it was allowed to smoke. The smoke is now in the circulating system. Is there a way to clean this? The MBP is "smoking" now, producing old smoke smell around it.

Comment: MacBook as in "new 2015 super-thin super-fanless MacBook"?

Comment: Or, to borrow Phil Schiller's quote, the #macbooklust MacBook?

Comment: @user24601 first retina 13" MBP

Comment: First of all, you should tell your MacBook that smoking is bad for its health, and to get some patches or something and try to quit.

Comment: @Rampant You sir, won the internet for today.

Answer (score 4):

To start, you'll want to power off your MacBook Pro, and clean it thoroughly (but carefully) with a microfiber towel. If you do this dry, you run the risk of abrasion and scratches, but you also don't want to soak your MacBook Pro with any liquid.

**External Cleaning**
Use an electronics screen cleaning liquid, preferably one with an "Apple Approved" label. Don't use anything alcohol-based or otherwise corrosive externally, as it will damage the rubber and plastic parts. Spray the cleaner directly on the microfiber towel, not your MacBook Pro.

Most Apple approved screen cleaning liquids leave a thin film you allow to dry, then gently polish away, not unlike wax on a car. Avoid open ports, thoroughly but gently clean the keyboard, hinge area, and speakers. These areas tend to accumulate a lot of gunk.

**Internal Cleaning**
Here's a step-by-step tear-down of the 2013 MacBook Pro.

https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Late+2013+Teardown/18695

In addition to their required tools, you will need:
• Electronics Cleaning Liquid, usually sold as "Screen Cleaning Liquid"
• Microfiber Screen Cleaning Cloths
• Electronics Cleaning Swabs (lint free Q-tips) *optional*
• Paper Towels
• 70% or (ideally) 90% Isopropyl Alcohol 
• Medium bristle toothbrush or paintbrush (optional)

You may want to invest in an anti-static wristband: They're inexpensive, and will save sensitive electronic parts. If you do not have one, disassemble your MacBook on a wood or metal surface, protected by a static-free towel: Microfiber works well, but only the "smooth" type, not the terrycloth type.

In Step 12 of the tear-down, you will see the fans being removed. This is optional: A good cleaning with canned air will most likely rid you of the problem. Take care not to blow the fans around too much. You won't clean them this way, and it may be bad for the motors. As an "extreme cleaning" option, replacing the fans will also get rid of the smell.

Take special care in wiping out the aluminum bottom case door -- The bare aluminum door, not the electronics -- with an electronics cleaner and a microfiber cloth or paper towel. Dirt, dust and debris tends to accumulate there.

You *can* gently clean the circuit boards in your MBP with 70% or 90% Alcohol (*do not use Rubbing Alcohol with high water content*), but this will depend on your comfort level working with electronics. Avoid the battery while doing this. Isopropyl evaporates quickly, and is used for liquid damage remediation for this reason. I have used it to thoroughly clean my 2009 MacBook Pro several times, and am typing on it right now.

Be careful and gentle with the electronics, and clean it well. Good luck!

Comment: Great advice. I would also say, perform the cleaning in stages. 1) power off and surface cleaning / keyboard / unibody and screen 2) Remove bottom case and clean/replace the fans and lightly clean any areas with q-tips if you can see tar caked. Use static safe procedures and a grounding strap. 3) Get advice or training and remove the battery / logic board and clean under things. If tar is in the keys and key mechanism or the speaker perforations, even a deep cleaning might not make it odor free for months to come.

Answer (score 4):

I do not recommend you open it to clean with liquids: too much can happen.

As for the exterior (including screen and keyboard) feel free to clean that.

As for the interior, and to clean the fans, I recommend to expose it vaporizer smell of your choice and let it run for a day in that kind of environment. That will compensate for the nicotine smell after a while.

Comment: Good advice, I edited my OP to clarify how any screen cleaner should be used, i.e., don't spray it on the Mac especially near open ports. I've never had an issue, but it's certainly possible.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the particulate matter (tars) from the cigarettes and other combustables have accumulated on the internal components. Given enough time (months or years) with fans running, the smell will dissipate. If the MacBook is still under warrantee, take it to an Apple Genius Bar and ask them what to do. You can also call Apple Care and ask them as well. Opening up and giving the internals a through clean, while technically possible, is a task left up to experts. If you are not an expert, do not try this. Leave it up to professionals.

[A similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/434780/how-can-i-remove-the-smell-of-cigarettes-from-my-computer), answered in great detail about Desktop PC CPU boxes, can be found on StackExchange. Some of the images are quite graphic and not for the faint-of-heart.

Another suggestion is to put it in an airtight box for a *long time* with activated charcoal (such as one uses for aquariums.) The charcoal should eventually absorb the odor.

Lastly, if this computer is the property of your employer, request a replacement, then find a smoke-free workplace.